# как скачать файл с помощью html в определенное место

Tags: html, файлы

для скачки файла использовал вот такой код: `<a href ="test.exe">download</a></td>`
но при нажатии вылазит окно в котором нужно выбрать куда установить файл, можно ли сделать так чтоб при нажатии на кнопку download программа автоматически устанавливалась например на рабочий стол

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее всего настройки браузера нужно смотреть

Comment: а можно сделать чтоб всем пользователям вне зависимости от настроек программа устанавливалась по нужной директории?

Answer (score 0):

Это регулируется исключительно настройками в браузере самим пользователем и никак иначе.

Принудительно сохранить пользователю файл в любую папку, которую вы, как разработчик, заходите - не представляется возможным в целях безопасности. Т.к. любой вредитель сможет сохранить пользователю любой файл куда угодно, что не прикольно. Представляете, вы приходите на сайт, а вам автоматом на комп в папку скачивается вирус?

А в браузере пользователь это настраивает примерно так: заходит в настройки, ставит папку куда хочет чтобы файл сохранялся и убирает галочку "всегда указывать место для скачивания" или что-то типа того